# How to render .dae(collada) file in android studio using openGL

Tags: java, android-studio, opengl-es, collada

I am developing a android project to make and render a 3D Object using openGL concepts. I'm able to rendering obj and mtl file

**Unfortunately, I'm not able to render .dae(collada) file in android studio.**

Any one send a sample project link for basic animated file in openGL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this repo:

https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer

`ColladaLoader` class has the code to parse the data in a dae file.