# Is there any way to use .dae (collada) file on android studio / Java?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, collada

We are working on a project that uses collada files. Our last resort is Unity 3d but that is heavier for the device. Is there anyway to use those files with android studio / java?

Comment: To read them? or to use them as an actual model? If you mean just reading, google implies it's just XML, which is easy to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about "using" collada files in terms of rendering them in your app, android runs OpenGL, so if you can set up a rendering context for that, you should be able to render a collada file (albeit with a bit more work than just using Unity).

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204593/how-to-render-daecollada-file-in-android-studio-using-opengl), with a similar question.